# Load YouTube outside Application

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, youtube

I have a simple UIWebView showing a page including YouTube thumbnail. When I click it, it loads it inside the application, but I want it to be loaded outside application in the YouTube-app.
How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as loading the YouTube-video-url like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcde12345"]];
```

It won't work in the simulator because it doesn't have the YouTube-app, but it will work on the iPhone (i hope, untested).

**EDIT:**
Here is an example of what you could do to catch the YouTube-urls and opening them in the YouTube-app instead of in your app:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    // Determine if we want the system to handle it.
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    if ([url.host isEqual:@"youtube.com"] && ([url.query rangeOfString:@"watch"] != 0)) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This is not tested, but should work :)

Comment: That won't work with me because YouTube thumbnail is in UIWebView content.

Comment: Then you'll need to catch all URLs going to youtube, I will add an example in my answer in a minute. :)

Comment: That isn't working because shouldStartLoadWithRequest isn't called when I click YouTube thumbnail.

Comment: That's really odd.. I think you should make another question about that (catching a thumbnail-click), but when you've got that, my answer will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

From http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

> **Method 2: Embed the YouTube player in a UIWebView**
>
> No, the iPhone still doesn't do Flash, but if you haven't already
>   noticed, the Safari browser on the iPhone is clever enough to turn any
>   YouTube embed into a clickable thumbnail that launches the native
>   YouTube player app on the phone. You can take advantage of this
>   feature in your app by using a UIWebView. Here's how:
>
> 1. Set up a UIWebView in your app. You can make it part of a xib or create it programmatically. Size the UIWebView according to how large
>      you want the clickable thumbnail to be.
> 2. Grab the video url using the same method as the one described above.
> 3. Call the loadHTMLString:baseURL: method on the UIWebView instance with some carefully constructed HTML that contains the YouTube
>      embedded player code snippet and some supporting HTML to make sure
>      that the video thumbnail appears correctly. Set the base URL to the
>      URL of your website (it doesn't do anything here -- ordinarily
>      UIWebView uses it to handle relative URL links correctly).
>
> The best way to illustrate this is with a code snippet. Note the use
>   of the viewport HTML meta parameter and the consistent use of width
>   and height parameters throughout.
>
> // webView is a UIWebView, either initialized programmatically or
>   loaded as part of a xib.
>
> NSString *htmlString = @"       ";
>
> [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"http://www.your-url.com"]];
>
> One of the biggest benefits of this approach is that your app does not
>   have to quit in order for the video to start playing. In fact, the
>   iPhone will keep your app running in the background while it fires up
>   the YouTube player to play the video. After the video finishes playing
>   (or when the user hits "Done"), the user is automatically taken back
>   to your app. This experience is very similar to watching embedded
>   YouTube videos in the iPhone Safari browser and is just as seamless.

Comment: How can I disable it? I want native YouTube app.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what are you trying to 'disable'? I was under the impression the text above explains an alternative approach to implementing the functionality your attempting to gain.