# How to play from youtube on iphone without uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load YouTube outside Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673066/load-youtube-outside-application)

I need to start the `YouTube` player on the `iPhone` without `UIWebView`.

Like [this](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/106694779519321914509/albums/5705965539654656625/5705965543515047586?hl=en&q=free%20server&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=316l3819l0l4017l15l12l2l1l1l1l317l2332l2.4.5.1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1360&bih=566&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N).

Comment: What is your question? Narrow it down to one readable question

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/106694779519321914509/albums/5705965539654656625/5705965543515047586?hl=en&q=free+server&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=316l3819l0l4017l15l12l2l1l1l1l317l2332l2.4.5.1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1360&bih=566&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open YouTube application by just opening the URL:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:url];
```

You should use the media tag which points to the *application/x-shockwave-flash* media tag. Please note that you have to try this on the iPhone, as it does not work in the simulator.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/106694779519321914509/albums/5705965539654656625/5705965543515047586?hl=en&q=free+server&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=316l3819l0l4017l15l12l2l1l1l1l317l2332l2.4.5.1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1360&bih=566&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N

Comment: Updated the example URL and verified that it works the way the way as described by your photo. Please try again!

Comment: Please note that you MUST execute this on the real iPhone device when you try it.

Comment: @user977826 if this works for you as well, please accept this answer ;-)

Comment: it is work fine. but i dnt need uiapplication. plz see and click above link. i need that. [link]https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/106694779519321914509/albums/5705965539654656625/5705965543515047586?hl=en&q=free+server&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=316l3819l0l4017l15l12l2l1l1l1l317l2332l2.4.5.1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1360&bih=566&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N[/link]

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at. You have 2 options of showing a YouTube movie in an iPhone; 1) In a UIWebView 2) In the YouTube application. This is the 2nd option that you asked for.

Comment: I have executed my code and it looks **exactly** like your screenshot.

Comment: can we make youtube application in iphone?